# Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in MVC/MsSql

Tags: php, sql-server, json, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter as my framework and MsSql for my db, I have some question about my json script because its my first time to use it. whenever I load the page the table is just showing the "processing..." and when I search from my database, the error in the image appears.

I don't know if my stored procedure is not executing.

[image]

> dbo.SEARCH_gen048,'ASC',1,10,1,'3/11/2016' Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /home/development/public_html/rmt/application/models/navi_model.php

I didn't do anything with my codes involving this module, can I ask for a help here?

**Controller**

```
function search_gen048() {

$data['fDate']=$this->input->post('dateData');
$this->load->model('navi_model');
$this->navi_model->get_gen048($_GET);

}

    function get_gen048(){
    $this->load->model('navi_model');
    $this->navi_model->srch_gen048($_GET);


}
```

**Model**

```
function srch_gen048($data){


    $sEcho = intval($data["sEcho"]);
    $iDisplayStart = intval($data["iDisplayStart"]); //start of record
    $iDisplayLength = intval($data["iDisplayLength"]); //display size
    $pageNum = ($iDisplayStart/$iDisplayLength)+1; //page num
    $colSort = $data['iSortCol_0'];
    $dirSort = strtoupper($data['sSortDir_0']);

    $qString = "SEARCH_gen048";
    $qString .= "" . $colSort . ",";
    $qString .= "'" . $dirSort . "',";
    $qString .= "" . $pageNum . ",";
    $qString .= "" . $iDisplayLength . ",";
    $qString .= "" . $sEcho . ",";
    $qString .= "'" . $data['fromDate'] . "'";

    echo $qString;
    $this->db->query('set ansi_padding on
        set ARITHABORT on
        set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL on
        set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on
        set ANSI_NULLS on
        set ANSI_WARNINGS on
        set numeric_roundabort off');

    $res = $this->db->query($qString);
    $res = $res->result();

    $iTotalDisplayRecords   = 0;
    $iTotalRecords          = 0;
    if(count($res) > 0)
    {
        $iTotalDisplayRecords = intval($res[0]->TOTAL_ROWS); //used for paging/numbering; same with iTotalRecords except if there will be search filtering
        $iTotalRecords = intval($res[0]->TOTAL_ROWS); //total records unfiltered
    }

    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($sEcho),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotalRecords,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iTotalDisplayRecords,
        "aaData" => array()

    );

    if(count($res) > 0)
    {
        foreach($res as $row)
        {
                                $output['aaData'][] = array(
                                        $row->accnum,
                                        $row->accname,
                                        $row->add1,
                                        $row->accdate,
                                        $row->uname,
                                        $row->add4,
                                        $row->bzip,
                                        ''
                                        );
        }
    }
    return json_encode( $output );
}
```

**View**

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#acctable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo site_url() ?>/welcome/get_gen048",
    "sServerMethod": "GET",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "fromDate"   , "value": "<?php echo $_POST["fromDate"] ?>" } );
        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) {
        fnCallback(json);

        } );
        },
        "aoColumns": [
        { "sClass": "leftAligned"   , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
        { "sClass": "rightAligned"  , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
        { "sClass": "rightAligned"  , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
        { "sClass": "rightAligned"  , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
        { "sClass": "rightAligned"  , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
        { "sClass": "rightAligned"  , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false },
        { "sClass": "rightAligned"  , "bSortable" : true, "bAutoWidth": false }

        ]   

                            }); 
} );

</script>
From: <input  type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" readonly /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="dateData" id="dateData"/>
```

Comment: your code is like telling you that you have called SEARCH_gen048 in you navi_model.php.

Comment: Yah, I echo the $qString in my model to check if it is all working, and based on what I've echoed out, the `$qString .= "'" . $data['fDate'] . "'";` didn't fetch any data.

Comment: how did you use the `$qString` variable? seems your post is lacking some codes

Comment: okay I edited my post you can check the whole codes now

Comment: you use `$res = $this->db->query($qString);` but that is not a sql query then in the next line your trying to get the result thats the reason how you get the error about SEARCH_gen048